# Merging datasets to estimate a logit model

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I have two dataframes that contain the results of two different surveys (with different respondents):

```
DF1 <- data.frame(color = factor(c("Blue", "Brown", "Blue", "Brown", "Blue", "Brown", "Blue", "Brown")),
                 location = factor(c("California", "Nevada", "Nevada", "California", "California", "Arizona", "California", "Nevada")),
                 DF1respondent = factor(c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R8")))
DF2 <- data.frame(shape = factor(c("Square", "Square", "Round", "Square", "Round", "Round", "Square", "Round")),
                 location = factor(c("California", "Nevada", "Nevada", "California", "Arizona", "Nevada", "California", "Nevada")),
                 DF2respondent = factor(c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8")))
```

I would like to fit a logistic regression model that estimates the probability of `DF1` respondents having a specific `color` given  `DF2` respondents' `shape` in a particular `location`.

Merging the two datasets in R is easy enough, as is fitting the model with `location` as a control variable:

```
DF3 <- dplyr::full_join(DF1, DF2, by=c("location"))
mod.fit <- glm(color ~ shape + location, binomial(logit), DF3)
```

However, does `mod.fit` meet the stated criteria, matching the responses in `DF1` and `DF2`? Or is there a better way to estimate the effect of `shape` on `color` in specific `locations`?

Comment: What's unclear is how `DF1` and `DF2` should be merged. For instance, in your `DF3`, `R1` is connected to `A1`, `A4`, and `A7`. What does that mean?

Comment: There is no connection between respondents in the two dataframes (since they contain results of different surveys). I have changed the names of the `respondent` factors to emphasize the lack of overlap between these factors across the two dataframes. The only factor that overlaps between the two dataframes is `location`.

Comment: The way you run your regression seems fine to me. I just don't get the business logic behind a full merge of the two tables. After merging, you have 6 instances of "Blue-Square-California". What does that mean?

Comment: The result of the merge is admittedly a little odd. Can you think of a better way to merge the data?

Comment: That depends the relationship between the two tables, and what is it you are trying to do by merging them.

Comment: The relationship between the tables is that they contain the results of two different surveys with different respondents conducted in the same locations, and I want to estimate the probability of DF1 respondents having a specific color given DF2 respondents' shape in a particular location.

Comment: You need to be more specific with what you mean by "given DF2 respondents' shape in a particular location". DF1 and DF2 have no connection on individual respondent's level. They are connected on `location` level. Perhaps, a better way to summarize the two tables in one, is count the number of respondents with each `color`, and the number of respondents with each `shape`, for each location.